# Intercept C# HttpClient GetAsync

Tags: c#, httpclient, sendasync

I have a web project (C#, MVC5 but no WebAPI) and a simple HTTP REST client that is calling an external REST service and acquires an accessToken etcing.

I want to check the response from all my Get/PostAsync calls for statusCode 401 but I see that I can only override the `SendAsync` method when implementing the `DelegatingHandler`.

```
class CustomDelegatingHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    async protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
        {
```

Is there something else I can do so as not to change the implementation of all my async calls to use `SendAsync`?

(What I really really want to do is refresh the accessToken.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you're on the right track. You wouldn't need to change your calls to use `SendAsync` instead of `GetAsync`, `PostAsync`, etc though. Rather, you'd need to change how you instantiate `HttpClient`:

```
var client = new HttpClient(new CustomDelegatingHandlerTokenRefresher());
// GetAsync, PostAsync, etc will hit your handler
```

Comment: This solved my problem partially thanks! However, when instantiating my HttpClient like you say I get the error about the InnerHandler not being assigned. I try to fix as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13922618/the-inner-handler-has-not-been-assigned-using-webapi-delegating-handler but it seems that my Route doesn't provide overload for an HttpMessageHandler since I am not using WebAPI (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880306/asp-mvc-message-handlers-vs-web-api-message-handlers).
I am sending my http calls from another library project inside my MVC5 solution. Any thoughts on that?

Answer (score 4):

Use the **Decorator** or **Interceptor** pattern.

Example concrete decorator:

```
public class CustomDelegatingHandlerTokenRefresher : DelegatingHandler
{
    public CustomDelegatingHandlerTokenRefresher(DelegatingHandler handler)
    {
        InnerHandler = handler;
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
      HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        RefreshToken();
        return await InnerHandler.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should rather set the InnerHandler instead of declaring a new member and call base.SendAsync.