# How do I add an API key to a HttpClient in a ASP.NET MVC application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Assume a `HttpClient` having been set up to look like the following (as per standard called with a factory):

```
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("weather", weather =>
{
     weather.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5");
     weather.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);
}).SetHandlerLifetime(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
```

Now when using the `HttpClient` to call an API I would like to reference the API key directly from the client rather than instantiating or defining it in the separate controller class. How would I go about doing this? Is it possible and if yes how would I reference it?

Comment: net 8 how to add and use api key (this one is hardcoded in settings) https://code-maze.com/aspnetcore-api-key-authentication/

Answer (score 1):

Use IOptions pattern:

```cs
public class HttpClientSettings
{
    public string ApiKey{ get; set; }
}
```

In appsettings:

```json
{
  "HttpClientSettings": {
    "ApiKey": "Value1"
  }
}
```

In program.cs/startup.cs

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<HttpClientSetting>(Configuration.GetSection(nameof(HttpClientSettings)));
}
```

In the client:

```cs
public class TestService
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
    private readonly HttpClientSettings _httpClientSettings;

    public TestService(HttpClient httpClient, IOptions<MySettings> settings)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient;
        _httpClientSettings= settings.Value;
    }

    public async Task<string> DoSomethingAsync()
    {
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Api-Key", _httpClientSettings.ApiKey);
...
    
    }

}
```

Comment: If I go about defining it in the appsettings how would I invoke the value when using the HttpClient? Specifically, how would I refer to it when routing an endpoint from a string? Right now I refer to it from a const string defined value within the given class:

`HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = await client.GetAsync($"weather?q={cityName}&units=metric&cnt=1&APPID={apiKey}")`

Comment: Or using simply configurationmanager - or will the key be exposed by doing so?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to add APIKey when you're adding HttpClient to DI, Actually it's the best way:

```cs
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("weather", weather =>
{
    weather.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5");
    weather.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);

    weather.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("APIKEY", builder.Configuration["HttpClient:APIKey"]);

}).SetHandlerLifetime(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
```

By so, all Apis that are calling by HttpClient (weather) will use the APIKey, and no need to worry about it anymore.

Comment: This looks great - how would you refer to it in the endpoint though then?

Comment: @Aleksandar If you want to apply the api-key to all routes, you may need to use interceptors, so the idea is before sending request you attach api-key to the route, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29106664/intercept-c-sharp-httpclient-getasync